# Azure Powershell Job throws Error : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I have a command in my script called

`Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SqlServerName -DisplayName $SqlServerAdmin`

I have used proper values for these parameters. Thing is this command runs perfectly when I run it from Powershell ISE, but when I do the same in Azure Powershell Task in Azure DevOps, it returns an error saying:

```
2020-09-18T11:02:54.0670872Z ##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

I cant figure out what I am missing.

Comment: permission issue on the service principal  running the pipeline? what are the existing permissions/roles ?

Comment: When I go into the Roles and Adminstrators section of the service principal, 2 are listed there : Application administrator ; Cloud application administrator

Comment: you need to grant permission to your app to manange your SQL DB. in the IAM blade of the SQL SErver resource

Comment: I gave Owner access to the service principal for the subscription. Still I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for the same. We need to add the service principal to Directory readers using this command:

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Directory Readers"}).Objectid -RefObjectId <object-id>
```